# -server 'default' is an unknown server in the configuration file

Tags: java, config, resin

I'm upgrading resin on a webapp and i keep getting the following error

```
              Starting Resin on Tue, 19 Feb 2013 14:46:29 -0800 (PST)

        [13-02-19 14:46:31.640] {main}   Using Resin(R) Open Source under the GNU Public          License (GPL).

                     See http://www.caucho.com for information on Resin Professional,
                     including caching, clustering, JNI acceleration, and OpenSSL  integration.

com.caucho.config.ConfigException: -server 'default' is an unknown server in the            configuration file.
at com.caucho.server.resin.Resin.initTopology(Resin.java:1069)
at com.caucho.server.resin.Resin.initServletSystem(Resin.java:1275)
at com.caucho.server.resin.Resin.configure(Resin.java:997)
at com.caucho.server.resin.Resin.initMain(Resin.java:979)
at com.caucho.server.resin.Resin.main(Resin.java:1437)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
  -server 'default' is an unknown server in the configuration file.
```

Where do i find this default set? I didn't change anything in the config that would effect that. Any Ideas?

Comment: Works for me with the [following default settings](http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/9074/20130220064008.png). What Resin version do you use? Is it a clean and unmodified installation? I found a [discussion thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/resin-interest@caucho.com/msg05461.html) that may help. Here is the [server output log](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/4132/20130220064222.png).

Answer (score 2):

In Resin each JVM ("server") you use has a name, because Resin's configuration is designed around having multiple servers, i.e. clustered. A single server deployment is still a cluster in Resin. It's just a cluster with one server.

The standard configuration is designed to just work, but if you have an older configuration, Resin might not be able to find your specific server.

If your configuration has a named server "a", but you start Resin without specifying the server name, Resin will try to use the default server (id=""). If it can't find that server, it will complain.

If you start Resin with "start-all" instead of "console", Resin will start up all the servers on the local machine, i.e. anything listening to your IP address. This makes it easy to configure a test cluster or a machine with multiple Resin instances.

```
> resinctl start-all
```

In your resin.xml, you'll either have a  entry or in Resin 4, a .

```
<resin ...>
  <cluster id="app">
    <server id="" .../>
```

The above configuration defines the "default" server.

The standard Resin 4 configuration uses a server-multi, which means the servers are named "app-0", "app-1", ....

If you start with "console" or "start", you'll need to specify "-server app-0" on the command line.

```
> resinctl start -server app-0
```

In an IDE, you might need to specify the server. For example adding a command-line "-server app-0".